# How to fix: screen saver greys out but does not turn off the screen after update?

Tags: 14.04, updates, screensaver

Currently my settings are:

- grey off the screen to save power `checked`,
- turn off the screen after `3 mins`.

It worked fine until I did a mass update. It looks like `turn off` setting is not applied - screen goes grey but still shining and the mouse `cursor` stays full white.

What can be causing this? Any possible fixes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No more problem, after some update I think.